How can I have an advanced technology in my Earth-based setting that doesn't drastically change everything?
to provide further context: my world takes place on Earth, and the technology is called Ectenic Computing (EC).
EC is the use of a material known as ectoplasm as a component in computer hardware. ectoplasm is the pure essence of the souls of the dead, and essentially pure, condensed brain power.
ectoplasm follows multiple odd rules, including:

Being intelligent, ranging from the intelligence of a slime mold to full-blown sentience.

Being able to sense its environment and react to outside stimuli.

Being able to exist in superposition, wherein by observing a location it can exist in multiple locations at once.

Being able to change it environment based on its observations on that environment (ex. turning a room black-and-white because the photo it observed of that room was taken in black-and-white.)


In my planned setting, a single corporation had access to this technology, and it was largely abandoned and limited to research by the US government after an incident which resulted in deaths, injuries and possessions. they mainly used it to develop computers, game consoles and games. but is this even a plausible path to take the technology? with the power it potentially has, is it plausible to limit the social and technological impact it has, say, 10 years after the fact?
(edit): and if not preventing change, any way I could limit it?

We are not a brainstorming site. Asking us to come up with ideas for how your societies work is asking us to build your world for you instead of asking us to help you resolve some sufficiently scope limited worldbuilding problem.

Only if they didn't actually manufacture anything
I'm assuming this is going to be the kind of horror movie/game setting where a corporation worked with Things Man Was Not Meant to Know and subsequently their offices were permanently shuttered - all well and good and a well-trod path.
But.
If Ectenic-driven computers (or game consoles!) were sold to the general public, everyone would know about this technology.  There would be enormous ethical and religious concerns - people get upset enough about the LDS church posthumously baptizing dead folks, so how much more upset would they be if they found out Grandma's intellect was manifesting Creepers in Minecraft?
There's no way they could hide their tech if it was available for general sale.  Competitors would go out and buy a few of their computers for reverse engineering, and immediately notice something was up when there were slots to insert the ectoplasmic containment unit next to the CPU.
So, the way by which you mitigate this is that the disaster that ended the company has to occur before the company ever rolled anything out to the manufacturing floor.  Prototypes could exist, but as soon as the factory line is tooled up, the secret is blown.  Then you're back in the comfortable kind of setting enjoyed by the X Files or Warehouse 13 - technology that can be packed up into a few shipping crates and stored at a secret government black site, with the original research facility boarded up and locked.

As an addendum, the revelation of this technology's existence would prove conclusively that there is continuity of existence (of some sort) after death.  The ramifications of this to the general public would be explosive to say the least.

Mostly agree (+1), but consider if they manufacture only at workshop level and then keep all the EC hardware in their own server farms, with the publicly-released hardware (game consoles) consisting of dumb terminals or the equivalent.  Depending on the proximity required, users could still experience the benefits of the EC capabilities while the sensitive hardware would stay in a secure zone.  (The normal caveats requiring large numbers of people to keep a secret apply, since this kind of operation would require huge numbers of staff.)

It's less of an issue than you think... unless we're talking about a dramatic breakthrough
Technology doesn't exist in a vacuum. The science that allows (e.g.) quantum computing brought a LOT of other things with it: 3D printing, advanced cell phone networking, medical technology, and a whole lot more. It's actually very rare today that an invention — any invention — "changes everything."
It wasn't always so! As you go backwards in time you find inventions that really did... eventually... change everything. The transistor, radio waves, electricity... the wheel. But that's because the innovation curve flattens out as you go backward in time, meaning spectacular innovation causes a non-linear jump. But, as science increases three things increase with it:

The amount of available knowledge.
Easier access to that knowledge.
Simpler implementation of new ideas.

And the most common example of that is the incremental advancements in cell phones. In the last 20 years they've gone from small barely-adequate cordless telephones to hand computers that put my old Intel Pentium to absolute shame! Why doesn't it look like it changed everything?
Because incremental changes were implemented annually. Everybody is wowed by the new features, but nobody really notices how their lives are changing. 30 years ago wedding photography was still a booming business. Now it's on the rocks because so many people are taking so many automated digital pictures with telephones that represent tech that was cutting edge in a Sony DSL in the 90s that it's inevitable that a bunch of great pictures will float to the surface. So why pay for the pro? (That industry is re-inventing itself. The pros are no longer just experienced camera users, they're experts at staging scenes so the images carry more emotion. Just being fair.)
The gist of what I'm saying is that if your Ectenic computing is an island of innovation that has the ability to change everything, it means either you want it to stand out but you're stuck because you don't want a Colossus-style computer takeover of the world or you simply haven't fleshed out all the other technology that must exist so that it doesn't "change everything."
Summary

It's insanely rare for any particular innovation to "change everything." That's marketing-speak and hasn't been reality for a good 40-50 years. For something to "change everything" it would mean infusing itself into the everyday lives of first- and second-world countries inside of 6-12 months, max., and in such a way as to make people actually feel uncomfortable with the change. Suddenly inventing Star Trek replicators without the commensurate advances in food processing would cause a wave of GMO-esque horror. Frankly, if we're being honest, such an innovation hasn't happened in your lifetime and only barely happened once in mine with the advent of personal computing in the 1970s. It happened once again in my parent's lifetime with the advent of Penicillin in the 1940s. It's that rare.

As knowledge increases, innovation happens in smaller and smaller steps. This is because the amount of knowledge, access to that knowledge, and the ability to implement new ideas all improve.

You can't have your cake and eat it, too. Either (a) Ectenic computing is an island of innovation that changes everything and you need to accept that in your story or (b) you haven't fleshed out all the supporting technological changes that must have existed to bring about EC's development such that it can't change everything.


Notable worldbuilding issues

Nothing is godlike. As much as you think this technology has unearthly potential, that's really only in your head and not a reflection of reality at all. This technology will only be as powerful as you choose to make it. No more, no less. To make a point: we regularly host questions asking, "how do I defeat my godlike character?" The answer is always the same, "you can't without introducing an exploitable weakness." It's your job as the worldbuilder to implement that exploitable weakness. Nothing is godlike.

Game design feels like a pretty shallow reason to develop this tech. If it has half the value you're suggesting, something closer to climate or geological prediction or N-body problem solving would make more sense. A lot more sense. Think of how SETI's been farming out chunks of its analysis processing to individual computers for decades (research SETI@Home). You're replacing their use of distributed computing with something unholy and blasphemous, but useful! Assuming Berkley SETI's still doing that (I haven't participated in 10+ years), you need to look at what kinds of projects are being hosted on the service (go look at that "distributed computing" link). When I stopped using it, there was a fair number of research programs including biology, mathematics, astronomy, celestial mechanics, etc. Heck, predicting the stock market would be more plausible than game design. But I'm 58 years old. It might simply be that I grew up playing pinball and Asteroids (although I'm fond nowadays of Borderlands...).

You're asking for help excusing the potential power of this innovation without having first developed any of the consequences of its development and use. Or, at least, not sharing them. Are we out offing geniuses to feed the matrix? Are we desecrating graves? Is the storage medium becoming the size of a twinkie? This list of consequences is the first pool from which you can develop the exploitable weaknesses you need to achieve your goal.


P.S.: If you want what I suspect is an unusual application environment for EC, consider unsolved mathematics problems. There are a LOT of them. A computing system made up of living cognitive capacity would be ideal for problems like that — where innovation depends almost as much on intuition as it does rigorous application of the scientific method.

thank you for the detailed answer! to reply to a few of these: 1) it's definitely a bit shallow. the idea is that games in question are just one part of its use, a small experimental branch, yet the most impactful part of daily culture for the technology. everyone plays games, after all. I was thinking that maybe EC isn't sold as ectoplasm, but as some invention of the company which invented it, and either it got revealed for its true nature after a certain incident or covered up and heavily ruled-checked.

Dead on for most of the "innovation" parts, but (as in my answer), I feel like "Oh, by the way, ghosts are real and we can use them for computers" would change everything.  Not technologically, but certainly in terms of worldviews.

@jdunlop You're right about worldviews! I must admit that I took "change everything" only in the technological sense. A number of world religious leaders would be most appreciative.

I would say an equal number would be profoundly unappreciative.  Hindu gurus, for example, or other faiths that believe in immediate reincarnation or the permanent exultation of the soul.  "Guess what?  Nope!  You stick around and we can use you for computational substrate!"

@jdunlop Actually, that last sentence combined with a (e.g.) Buddhist metaphysical crisis would make a pretty good story. I like the idea better than what Carl Sagan did in Contact (which I thought was pretty shallow, but in his defense, it wasn't the story he wanted to tell... he just needed an excuse to blow something up).

"Nothing is godlike. As much as you think this technology has unearthly potential, that's really only in your head and not a reflection of reality at all." this even applies to the real world. Even when tech is created and proven to be superior to all existing alternatives you still need to integrate it into the world. You need a scalable process for creating/using the tech, you need to build or retrofits factories using that process, you need to source materials/ingredients, you need the logistics, you need distribution. That's just on the production side.

There is so much more - you need to train people to use and maintain it. Think mechanics, craftsmen, support people. These don't work for you but without them, your invention is dead in the water - pretty much nobody will buy your 3D floating TV or whatever you have, if it can just turn into an expensive brick with no way to fix it. With the infrastructure to make and maintain the thing sorted, you can then think about the end user buy-in. It's rare that tech will just immediately have all these concerns sorted and thus immediately adopted.
